# Нужен совет Java массив

Tags: java, массивы

Есть следующий цикл:

```
        while (b > 0){
            c = a % b;
            massM[i] = c;
            a = b;
            massA[i] = a;
            System.out.print(massA[i] + " ");
            b = c;
        }
```

При вводе а = 525, b = 231; массив massA[i] имеет вид {231, 63, 42, 21} как сделать так что бы получался массив {525, 231, 63, 42, 21} т.е вводимое а становилось в начало массива .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код:

```
int a = 525;
int b = 231;
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
arr.add(a);
arr.add(b);
while (arr.get(arr.size() - 1) != 0) {
    arr.add(arr.get(arr.size() - 2) % arr.get(arr.size() - 1));
}
for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(arr.get(i));
}
```

Вывод:

> 525
>   231
>   63
>   42
>   21
>   0

---

Если ноль в конце не нужен, то есть следующие варианты:

1. Удалять последний элемент по завершению цикла `while`.
2. Не выводить последний элемент.
3. Добавить проверку внутри цикла `while`:

   ```
   int c;
   while (arr.get(arr.size() - 1) != 0) {
       c= arr.get(arr.size() - 2) % arr.get(arr.size() - 1);
       if (c!=0)
       arr.add(c);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

поменять местами строки `a = b;` и `massA[i];`

Comment: Делал в таком случае пропадает последний элемент массива: {525, 231, 63, 42}

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?